# Thumbnail image created from server video url keeps changing when scroll tableview

Tags: swift, scroll, lag

in my app i have successfully created thumbnail image from video url and display in table cell but the problem is when i scroll tableview cell the thumbnail image keeps on changing. How to solve this. Please help me with this issue as i have tried searching but no luck

my code tried:
my cell class code:-

```
class VideoCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let cellID = "VideoCell"
      
    //MARK:- Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var videoThumbImage: UIImageViewX!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIViewX!
    @IBOutlet weak var userProfileImage: UIImageViewX!
    @IBOutlet weak var playBtn: UIButton!
    
    //MARK:- Properties
    var chatObj:ModelOldMessagesMessages? {
        didSet {
            configure()
        }
    }
    
    //MARK:- Life Cycle
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        self.mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.mainView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner,.layerMinXMaxYCorner]
    }
    
    //MARK:- Helpers
    private func configure() {
        guard let obj = chatObj else {return}
        
        if let msgStr = obj.chatMsgText, let time = obj.chatMsgDatetime, time.count > 0, msgStr.count > 0 {
            let time = convertUTCToLocal(timeString: time)
            self.dateLbl.text = changeDateForamte(time!, conVertFormate: "hh:mm a", currentDateFormate: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ")
            
            let imgStr = WS_Chat_DownloadFile + msgStr
            let url = URL(string: imgStr)!
            
            self.getThumbnailImageFrom(fileUrl: url) { (image) in
               self.videoThumbImage.image = image
            }
        }
        if let tmpImgURL = obj.adminImage, tmpImgURL.count > 0 {
            let img = WS_DownloadImage + tmpImgURL
            self.userProfileImage.loadImage(img)
        }
        
    }
    
    fileprivate func getThumbnailImageFrom(fileUrl: URL, completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> Void){
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
             let asset = AVAsset(url: fileUrl)
             let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
             imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            
             let thumbnailTime = CMTimeMake(value: 2, timescale: 1)
            
            do {
                let thumbnailCGImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: thumbnailTime, actualTime: nil)
                let finalImage = UIImage(cgImage: thumbnailCGImage)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(finalImage)
                }
                
            } catch let err {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

my cellforrow function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
    
        let dict = oldMessageArr[indexPath.row]
         
let videoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: VideoCell.cellID) as! VideoCell
            videoCell.chatObj = dict
            videoCell.playBtn.tag = indexPath.row
            videoCell.playBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePlayBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
        return videoCell
    }
```

my main controller class file code where chat api is being called according to timer:

```
//MARK:- Life Cycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    registerCell()
    setupRefreshControl()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    WS_GetOldMessagesAPI()
    self.newMessagesLoadTimer.invalidate()
}

func setupRefreshControl() {
    refresher.tintColor = .black
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData), for: .valueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)
}

@objc func refreshData() {
   self.WS_GetOldMessagesAPI()
}

@objc func timerAction() {
    self.newMessagesLoadTimer.invalidate()
    self.WS_getNewMessage()
}
 

func WS_getNewMessage()
    {
        var url = String()
        
        let model = ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.getLoginModel()
        
        if let c_id = model?.loginDataResult?.chatRoomsId {
            self.chatRoomId = c_id
        }
        
        var offset = Int()
        let dict = oldMessageArr.last
        if let offID = dict?.chatMsgId {
            offset = offID
        }
        
        url = WS_GET_OldChatMessage+"\(chatRoomId)"+"?"+"offsetID=\(offset)"
        
        APIClient<ModelBaseOldMessages>().API_GET(Url: url, Params: noParams, Authentication: true, Progress: false, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (modelResponse) in
            
            if(modelResponse.success == true) {
                if offset == 0 {
                    self.getNewMessageArr.removeAll()
                    if let data = modelResponse.oldMessagesMessages, data.count != 0 {
                        for item in data {
                            if let id = item.chatMsgId, self.newMessageIDsArr.contains(id) == false {
                                self.newMessageIDsArr.append(id)
                                self.getNewMessageArr.append(item)
                                self.tableView.scrollToBottom()
                            }
                        }
                     
                        self.newMessagesLoadTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } else {
                    if let data = modelResponse.oldMessagesMessages, data.count != 0 {
                        for item in data {
                            if let id = item.chatMsgId, self.newMessageIDsArr.contains(id) == false {
                                self.newMessageIDsArr.append(id)
                                self.getNewMessageArr.append(item)
                            }
                        }
                        
                        self.newMessagesLoadTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                self.newMessagesLoadTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }) { (failed) in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func WS_GetOldMessagesAPI() {
        
        var url = String()
        var offset = Int()
        
        let model = ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.getLoginModel()
        
        if let c_id = model?.loginDataResult?.chatRoomsId {
            self.chatRoomId = c_id
        }
        
        let dict = oldMessageArr.first
        if let offID = dict?.chatMsgId {
            offset = offID
        }
        
        url = WS_GET_OldChatMessage+"\(chatRoomId)"+"?"+"offsetID=\(offset)"
        
        APIClient<ModelBaseOldMessages>().API_GET(Url: url, Params: noParams, Authentication: true, Progress: true, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (modelResponse) in
            
            print("---------------------")
            print("Result:",modelResponse.toJSONString(prettyPrint: true)!)
            print("---------------------")
            
            if(modelResponse.success == true) {
                if let data = modelResponse.oldMessagesMessages, data.count != 0 {
                    let neweReverseData = data.reversed()
                    for item in neweReverseData
                    {
                        if let id = item.chatMsgId, self.oldMessageIDsArr.contains(id) == false
                        {
                            self.oldMessageIDsArr.insert(id, at: 0)
                            self.oldMessageArr.insert(item, at: 0)
                        }
                    }
                    self.refresher.endRefreshing()
                    self.reloadTable()
                    
                    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: data.count - 1, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
                }
                self.WS_getNewMessage()
            } else {
                self.refresher.endRefreshing()
                self.reloadTable()
            }
        }) { (failed) in
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
            self.reloadTable()
        }
    }
```

Comment: pls help me with this issue

Comment: Show the `cellForRowAt` function. You probably aren’t cleaning out data for the cell’s reuse.

Comment: In cell for row i am simply assigning data like videocell.chatobj = oldmessages[indexpath.row]

Comment: Now where should i change in my above code sir

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your configure function, before getting and setting thumbnail, add

```
self.videoThumbImage.image = nil
```

Comment: U mean in awakefromnib function right i should do imagwview.image = nil

Comment: Ok i wiill try at let you know sir

Comment: actually it works but it keeps on flashing like first blank and then show image then again blank and then show image because it is a chat message cell where every 5 seconds the api run for new messages..Editing my code

Comment: please help some one